# How can I get image from UIWebView cache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`will simply download the image again.

I wonder if I can get the cached images after the `UIWebView` is completely loaded.

Comment: I can't understand your question will you please elaborate.

Comment: I mean after a webview is loaded, some images will be downloaded as cache, right? Can I access those image data?